# jQuery autocomplete enter key angolia

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, algolia

Currently the autocomplete action when pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key on a selected element is to put that elements value into the input box.

How can I modify the behavior so that pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key on an element triggers that elements embedded url. To simplify I'd like to make the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key have the same behavior as a mouse click on a returned element.

Thanks

```
$('#search_input').autocomplete(
        { 
            //autoselect: true,
            //autoselectOnBlur: true,
            hint : false,
            templates: {
                dropdownMenu: '#my-custom-menu-template',
            }
        }, 
        [
            {
              source: $.fn.autocomplete.sources.hits(indexProducts, { hitsPerPage: 5 }),
              name : 'products',
              displayKey: 'name',
              templates: {
                suggestion: function(suggestion) {                    
                  return '<a href="'+suggestion.url+'">'+suggestion._highlightResult.name.value+'</a>';
                }
              }
            },
            {
              source: $.fn.autocomplete.sources.hits(indexCategories, { hitsPerPage: 5 }),
              name : 'categories',
              displayKey: 'name',
              templates: {
                suggestion: function(suggestion) {
                  return '<a href="'+suggestion.url+'">'+suggestion._highlightResult.name.value+' en <b>' + suggestion.parent_name+'</b></a>';
                }
              }
            }
        ]).on('autocomplete:selected', function(event, suggestion, dataset) {
    console.log(suggestion, dataset);
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution add autocomplete:selected event:**

```
$('#search_input').autocomplete(
        { 
            //autoselect: true,
            //autoselectOnBlur: true,
            hint : false,
            templates: {
                dropdownMenu: '#my-custom-menu-template',
            }
        }, 
        [
            {
              source: $.fn.autocomplete.sources.hits(indexProducts, { hitsPerPage: 5 }),
              name : 'products',
              displayKey: 'name',
              templates: {
                suggestion: function(suggestion) {                    
                  return '<a href="'+suggestion.url+'">'+suggestion._highlightResult.name.value+'</a>';
                }
              }
            },
            {
              source: $.fn.autocomplete.sources.hits(indexCategories, { hitsPerPage: 5 }),
              name : 'categories',
              displayKey: 'name',
              templates: {
                suggestion: function(suggestion) {
                  return '<a href="'+suggestion.url+'">'+suggestion._highlightResult.name.value+' en <b>' + suggestion.parent_name+'</b></a>';
                }
              }
            }
        ]).on('autocomplete:selected', function(event, suggestion, dataset) {
                location.href = suggestion.url;
            });
```